# Using Chef without a Chef Server. (Chef Solo)

Tags: chef-infra, chef-solo

Can I store all the cookbooks, roles, environments on a different machine or may be GITHUB account and use chef solo to pull them and run them on the host machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your solo.rb points to the directory where the files are ultimately located (i.e. "cookbook_paths" : "/path/to/cookbooks"), it does not matter how you get them there.

For instance, I recently had a scenario where I needed to download a .zip of my cookbooks directory from Bitbucket (a service similar to Github) to the node before running chef-solo.

Comment: Can I add the same Github url to "cookbook_paths" on multiple machines that run chef-solo. Basically, I want multiple machines that are running chef-solo to be able to pull cookbooks, roles, environments, etc from the same Github url.